# I get LNK2028 when trying to wrap native c++ class using managed c++

Tags: managed, managed-c++

trying to wrap a native cpp class using managed c++ class.

all looks good but for some reason it wont compile.

getting the following linker errors:

Error   25  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0002CE)
Error   27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Any ideas how do I fix this one ? :\

well, here is a full error of one of the functions:

Error   20  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0002CF) "public: bool __thiscall RCSclient::ResumeChannel(char *,int,__int64)" (?ResumeChannel@RCSclient@@$$FQAE_NPADH_J@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __clrcall RCSClientWrapper::RCSclientWrapper::ResumeChannel(class System::String ^,int,class System::DateTime ^)" (?ResumeChannel@RCSclientWrapper@RCSClientWrapper@@$$FQ$AAM_NP$AAVString@System@@HP$AAVDateTime@4@@Z) RCSClientWrapper.obj    RCSClientWrapper

Tried to add the  user32.lib with no results..

Ofer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++/CLI allows you
to mix in native C++ pretty much at will, but using C++/CLI makes your app
depend on the .NET framework.

The reason is your C++/CLI project doesn't have some libs (user32.lib, in example) setup in the linker input is that the .NET framework already provides similar services, and the
IDE assumes that you prefer those to the older, native ones.

Check your project and add reference to the corresponding library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot an virtual keyword into the native C++ header function declaration 
to call from managed wrapper!?